# Stop Navigation Bar After Last Item

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to stop after item #6.

I want the vertical dividing line and the dark space after it to be deleted.  I then want item #6 to have rounded corners at the end of it - the same way that item #1 starts.

http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/6ykVS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your navigation to look like Apple's menu bar. So made changes to your CSS & added some also. Please have a look. I think you like it this way.

**Here is the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6ykVS/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav { width: auto; } /* this may reduce the extra space after the menu */

#nav li:last-child {  } /* this helps to write css for last li element */
```